# React Native Building a Video Call function using expo go

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, videochat

I am new to React Native development and I have been working on my first app using expo. Now I need to add a video call function to my app. How can I add a video call function using expo?

Comment: Wtih expo managed workflow you can use [expo-camera](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/) just open the snack can copy the code to get started

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can integrate video calls in the app with WebRTC - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webrtc.

> **Expo** - Sadly this module is not available in the [Expo Go](https://expo.dev/client) app by default due to including much needed native code. However you can get things working via the [expo-dev-client](https://docs.expo.dev/development/getting-started/) library and out-of-tree [config-plugins/react-native-webrtc](https://github.com/expo/config-plugins/tree/master/packages/react-native-webrtc) package.

Comment: thank you. I am trying to install expo-dev-client and when I try to run "eas build" I get "zsh: command not found: eas" how can I solve this?

Comment: Follow this guide - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=id0Im72UN6w&t=25s